# Mod Cluster Manger webpage not accessible

Tags: apache, mod-cluster

I have downloaded latest apache lounge and mod_proxy_cluster_2.0.0Alpha . Added mod_proxy_cluster.conf file to extra folder. Included this conf file in http.conf file and copied *.so files to modules. When i try to access mod_cluster_manager webapp it's not available but root page says "It works". Can you please let me know what's wrong am i doing.

```
Include conf/extra/mod_cluster.conf


LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so
LoadModule cluster_slotmem_module modules/mod_cluster_slotmem.so
LoadModule manager_module modules/mod_manager.so
LoadModule advertise_module modules/mod_advertise.so

MemManagerFile "cache/mod_cluster"

<IfModule manager_module>
  Listen 6666
  # This is a special VirtualHost that receives service messages from worker nodes.
  # Access to this VirtualHost should be restricted.
  <VirtualHost *:6666>
    <Directory />
      Require ip 127.0.0.1 ::1
    </Directory>
    ServerAdvertise on
    AdvertiseGroup 224.0.1.105:23364
    EnableMCPMReceive

    # Access to this management console should be restricted.
    <Location /mod_cluster_manager>
      SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
      Require ip 127.0.0.1 ::1
   </Location>
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just uncommented below line in httpd.conf as it is mandatory for mod_cluster

`LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).